# return type double not working with recursive function in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

For some reason I'm getting the error: "The method must return a result of type double" with

```
public static double power0(double d, int n)
{
   if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    else if (n > 0)
        return d * power0(d, n - 1);
}
```

This clearly has a return type of double and yet I get an error message before compiling and in the code.

Comment: if (n == 0)
        return (double)1;
    else if (n > 0)
        return d * power0(d, n - 1);
else 
return (double)-1;

Comment: What does the method return if n is -5?

Comment: you know, some error messages are also readable

Comment: @MarkusKull I can see why this error message could be confusing for a less-experienced programmer.  The method *does* return a result of type double (in two places)--it just doesn't do that on all possible paths.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if I've ever seen this in other editors. I know it's a range issue but is this built into Eclipse where other compilers it's not?

Answer (score 4):

It complains because you are not returning a value for a case when n is below 0.

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure if I've ever seen this in other editors. I know it's a range issue but is this built into Eclipse where other compilers it's not?

Comment: @user4849361 Every Java compiler will give you the same error. There is still one return statement missing...

Comment: Ok, but why does it need to cover every value range (here if n < 0)? What if I wanted this on purpose so I could handle an exception a certain way? I would always have to handle the exception in a third return statement?

Comment: You have a code like this ``if (a) ... else if (b) ...`` so the compiler knows that there is a condition different than ``a`` and ``b`` for which you did not specify a return value. Instead of return statemet you can throw an exception.